# ExtJS: In Firefox browser on a <div> element, onClick listener fails to call a URL with a href call in progress

Tags: javascript, firefox, extjs, onclick, dom-events

The following code works fine in Chrome but in Firefox Firebug add-on, the store reload call is shown red with no errors and nothing in return value. The same call in Firefox if made in a new Tab returns fine results. Also if the href is made # , then the reload call works fine.

How can I correct this so that both the calls are made fine when the MyFileName link is clicked in all browsers?

```
'<div id ="myId"> <a  href="/downloadFile/' + fileId + '.pdf" > MyFileName</a></div>'

        Ext.get('myId').on('click', function() {
//The below call doesn't load results in FF browser
     Ext.getCmp('myGrid').getStore().reload();
        }, null, { delay: 1 });
```

Comment: Which version of Ext are you using ?